# page stop responsing , when jquery request ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.get(
'http://request.url',function(response){
document.write(response.returnText);
});
```

the ajax url need a long time to response, when this request is processing, the page will not response, such as all of elements of links can not be clicked.

I know ajax is a async request, and don't block main (page) thread, but everybody, why the page not responsed?

Comment: Your problem might be the content you are loading. Nothing can be said without more info.

Comment: firebug tell me the main request is finished. but I see firebug didn't tell us more things, I can't see many async request are not ajax and not shown in firebug's console.